# Getting value of nested object

Tags: javascript, object, arraylist

I have the following object in which I need to retrieve the "address" fields value.

```
var south= {};
south.address = {
    "South Building" :{
        address: "7421 New York Avenue",
        address2: "",
        city: "Georgetown",
        state: "DC",
        zip: "10221",
        phone:"202.555.9999",
        fax: "202.555.6696"
    }
};
```

I can only currently get the name of the field with:

```
Object.keys(south.address["South Building"])
```

which returns: `["address", "address2", "city", "state", "zip", "phone", "fax"]`

or 
`Object.keys(south.address["South Building"])[0]`

which returns: `"address"`

I want to get the value of "address". Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the key that you retrieved:

```
var key = Object.keys(southland.address["SoCal Accounting"])[0];
var value = southland.address["SoCal Accounting"][key];
```

And for your array of keys:

```
var keys = Object.keys(southland.address["SoCal Accounting"]);
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    console.log(southland.address["SoCal Accounting"][key]);
}
```

Comment: That works! I didn't need the for loop though, the value variable was what I needed. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The real question I have for you is does that object change? 
If it doesn't change you can access the address attribute as such:

`south.address["South Building"].address`

If it does change (I would assume that `"South Building"` is most likely to change) but the overall structure is the same you would access the address of each "building" in a for loop like this

```
for(var building in south.address){
    var address = south.address[building].address;
    //do what you want with address here.
}
```

If in fact the structure of the inner object changes (i.e. `address` is not a gauranteed attribute) then you could still access it if it exists like this:

```
for(var building in south.address){
    if("address" in south.address[building]){
       var address = south.address[building].address;
       //do what you want with address here.
    }
}
```